# I wanted to download web content but it isn't working properly

Tags: java, android, download

I wanted to download a website and display the content as a string to the Logs, but first the app takes hours to load and if it loads, I don't get the sourcecode of the website.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data!= -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

                return "Failed";

            }


        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;

        try {

            result = task.execute("http://www.kicker.de/").get();


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Log.i("Contents of URL", result);


    }


}
```

Comment: Never use `execute().get()`. It defeats the purpose of the Asynctask

Comment: And did you not see the documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use BufferedReader to get actual data read from InputStreamReader

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urls[0]);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
              html.append(line);
        }

        return html.toString();

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

        return "Failed";

    }
    finally{
        in.close();

    }

}
```

}